# Made an etch-a-sketch that works on JSFiddle but not on Github Pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I made a simple etch-a-sketch that seems to be working on Codepen:                      https://codepen.io/Chango-/pen/GEBpbx

```
<head>
  <title>Etch-a-Sketch</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"></link>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <h4>The Greatest Etch-A-Sketch in the Universe</h4>

  <center>
    <button class="newGrid btn btn-primary" type="button">New sketch!</button>
    <button class="randomColor btn btn-primary">Random Color</button>
  </center>


  <div id="container"></div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

I'm trying to deploy the static site on Github but the JQuery doesn't seem to be working even though the script is included in the HTML file. Not sure what's the problem

Link to Github repo: https://github.com/CGrijalva90/etch-a-sketch

Link to Github page: https://cgrijalva90.github.io/etch-a-sketch/

Comment: yeah ... your github.io page loads jQuery, good start, but there's absolutely no other javascript loaded - i.e. you're not loading `EtchaSketch.js` in the page

Comment: Grrrr... Yeah the CSS doesn't seem to be working either upon inspecting the site. No clue why the js file isn't loading. I made the master branch be the source for the page.

Comment: `No clue why the js file isn't loading` - well, for a start, there's no script tag for it in the html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the script tag to your html

```
<script src="./EtchaSketch.js"></script>
```

Also fix the css tag in your head with the right href

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./EtchaSketch.css">
```